# Is “uncounted day” the right term for this case?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

There’s a 30-day term, and I need to account for 2 days off by extending the term to 32 days. Can use the term like this?:

> Term: 01/01/19 – 01/02/19 (2 **uncounted days** on 01/05/19 and 01/13/19)

Comment: ***A*** *2-day off* doesn't sound right. It should be ***a*** *2-day-off period* or just *2 days off*.

Comment: You’re right. I’ll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your context isn't clear, but I don't think "uncounted" is suitable because it can mean that you have omitted, or neglected to count them.

A better term might be *excluded*, as this makes clear that you *have* accounted for them and declared that they are *not* part of the term.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean: The days are not part of the term.